# Python - main function helpb

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, tuples, shopping-cart

```
Please enter a command: ls
No recipe in meal plan yet.
Please enter a command: ls -a
chocolate peanut butter banana shake
chocolate brownies
seitan
cinnamon rolls
peanut butter
omelette
Please enter a command: g
Please enter a command: add peanut butter
Please enter a command: ls
[('peanut butter', '300 g peanuts,0.5 tsp salt,2 tsp oil')]
Please enter a command: g
| 300.0 | g | peanuts |
| 0.5 | tsp | salt |
| 2.0 | tsp | oil |
```

If I want create this output, what should I do in the main function?

```
while not quit_program:
        command = input("Enter a command: ")
        
        if command.lower() == "h":
            print("Help message goes here.")
        elif command.lower() == "q":
            quit_program = True
        elif command == "Is":
            if not meal_plan:
                print('No recipe in meal plan yet.')
        elif command == "rm":
            remove_function(get_ingredient_amount)
        elif command.lower() == "g":
            generate_shopping_list(recipes)
        elif command == "add":
            add_to_shopping_list(get_recipe_name, shopping_list)
        elif command == "ls -a":
            list_all_recipes()
        elif command == "ls -s":
            display_shopping_list(shopping_list)
        elif command.lower() == "mkrec":
            create_recipe()
        else:
            for recipe, ingredients in meal_plan.items():
                print(recipe)
            print("Invalid command. Please try again.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Do you really use Python 2 or why did you add that tag?

Answer (score 0):

can you provide more context to the problem. Or simply you can just put the above code inside main like

```
if __name__=="__main__":
quit_program=False
while not quit_program:
    command = input("Enter a command: ")
    
    if command.lower() == "h":
        print("Help message goes here.")
    elif command.lower() == "q":
        quit_program = True
    elif command == "Is":
        if not meal_plan:
            print('No recipe in meal plan yet.')
    elif command == "rm":
        remove_function(get_ingredient_amount)
    elif command.lower() == "g":
        generate_shopping_list(recipes)
    elif command == "add":
        add_to_shopping_list(get_recipe_name, shopping_list)
    elif command == "ls -a":
        list_all_recipes()
    elif command == "ls -s":
        display_shopping_list(shopping_list)
    elif command.lower() == "mkrec":
        create_recipe()
    elif command.lowe()== "quit":
        quit_program=True
    else:
        for recipe, ingredients in meal_plan.items():
            print(recipe)
        print("Invalid command. Please try again.")
```

or create a function like VanN did.

Also I made a little change to the code to prevent it from going into infinite loop. Hope it helps

Answer (score -2):

The simplest way is create a function and call it.

```
meal_plan = True
def myProgram():
  
  while True:
    command = input("Please enter a command: ")

    if command.lower() == "h":
      print("Help message goes here.")
    elif command.lower() == "q":
      #quit_program = True
      break
    elif command == "Is":
      if not meal_plan:
        print('No recipe in meal plan yet.')
    elif command == "rm":
      # remove_function(get_ingredient_amount)
      print('Call remove function')
    elif command.lower() == "g":
      # generate_shopping_list(recipes)
      print('Call generate_shopping_list(recipes)')
    elif command == "add":
      # add_to_shopping_list(get_recipe_name, shopping_list)
      print('Call add_to_shopping_list(get_recipe_name, shopping_list)')
    elif command == "ls -a":
      # list_all_recipes()
      print('Call list_all_recipes()')
    elif command == "ls -s":
      # display_shopping_list(shopping_list)
      print('Call display_shopping_list(shopping_list)')
    elif command.lower() == "mkrec":
      # create_recipe()
      print('Call create_recipe()')
    else:
      for recipe, ingredients in meal_plan.items():
          print(recipe)
      print("Invalid command. Please try again.")

myProgram()
```